# Cocos2d doesn't display retina images

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have some images, named "SomeImage.png" and "SomeImage-hd.png"( for retina).

Everything looks with non- retina display, **but retina images are not shown** and I do not understand why.

Instead, I see non-retina images.

How to solve this?

Comment: Can you please give us some code to work with. Atleast post the code where you load the images.

Comment: Have you called `[director enableRetinaDisplay:YES]`?

Comment: Really thanks, do not understand how i missed that!:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this code

```
 [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES]
```

Hope this helps.